# ssh getting disrupted intermittently

Tags: linux, ssh, redhat

I have Red Hat Linux Enterprise Edition 5 on my box. Recently, I started experiencing issues with sshd not keeping connection and randomly disconnecting with my clients.

Ping works perfectly fine but port 22 is blocked randomly.

Has anyone faced this issue? What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the duplicate IP address on your network.....  At least give me credit if I'm right...  :)

Comment: Check your arp table and compare when it does work and when it does not.  arp -a works on both windows and linux clients.

Comment: We have DHCP in place. My admin moved my machine to different network and i got new IP address. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you say ping works perfectly, how many pings are you sending? It sounds like ssh is working "perfectly" for at least some of the time. You need to run a long ping test to catch any intermittent issues.

That way you can establish whether there is some network issue causing the problem, which seems more likely for an intermittent issue.  Look for any patterns of time of day, or if it is specific clients disconnecting, while others work.

Comment: I tried ping -t <myhost>. It never skipped a packet. Very rarely the delay was odd >1ms.

Answer (score 0):

Put this into your sshd_config and kill/HUP your sshd process.

```
ClientAliveInterval 60
ClientAliveCountMax 5
```